# How does SEO work with a Custom HTML module as the "heading" of the article

Tags: seo, joomla

I am using Joomla CMS and I have a menu item that links to an article. I also have a Custom HTML module that I have place at the top/above that article, and in this custom module I have placed the `<h1>` tag for my page heading.

When a search engine crawls my site, will it see the `<h1>` in that module and consider it the `<h1>` to THAT article? Or do I need to put the `<h1>` tags in the article content itself for the search engines to apply it to that page? I'm new to SEO so I am not sure about this.

Comment: Very likely. You should not use the h1 tag or any other header tag for anything else but for the pages content.

Comment: Very likely Google will see it in the custom HTML module, or very likely I need to put the <h1> tag in the article content?

Comment: Look at the resulting HTML markup. By "article" I assume you are referring to the "Joomla article"? Search engines have no concept of this, they only see the rendered result.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yes I meant the Joomla article. Should that div be anywhere in particular in the markup in relation to that page/article? Or does it just need to be present in the HTML markup for a search engine to see it? Because at the moment, the module markup is sitting above the <!-- Page Content -->

Comment: I am not fully aware of what you are trying to do, but I think I understand some of it. If you are using a div, can't you place it low in the HTML code and use CSS to place it where you want?? Or is it that the custom module will appear basically the same from page to page and can be considered a page header?

Answer (score 1):

Search engines don't know or care whether content is rendered via a module or an article and only look at the source code of the page.

Ideally for SEO purposes your page should have exactly one H1 heading.

It doesn't matter whether the H1 heading is generated by the module or the article.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's the only  tag on the page Google should pick it up as the header for that particular article. Just remember that only one   tag should be used per article.